# How to create a tree-like array from a loop?

Tags: php, loops

Suppose I have a one-dimensional array `$arr` like this:

```
Array
(
    ['key1'] => 1
    ['key2'] => 1
    ['key3'] => 1
    ['key4'] => 1
)
```

I want to loop through `$arr` like this:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $a) {
   //$tree[????] = ????? Here is my concern
}
```

such that, doing `print_r($tree)` produces

```
Array
(
    ['key1'] => Array
    (
        ['key2'] => Array
        (
            ['key3'] => Array
            (
                ['key4'] => 1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My concern is how to increase the dimension (not the values) of the array `$tree` inside the loop from a single dimension array `$numbers` such that `$tree['key1']['key2']['key3']` is an array and `$tree['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4']` is equal to `1`.

Furthermore, if I have a single dimensional array `$foo` with 10 elements. I should produce another array `$bar` that expands to 10 dimensional array similar to the output above.

What should I do inside the `foreach` loop? Or instead of using loop, is there a way to produce an output like that of above from a one dimension array?

---

EDIT:

> OK well you obviously need some kind of recursive function, but can
>   you explain how you know that key2 should be a child of key1, key3
>   should be a child of key2 etc based on the data you show?

The next element of a 1D array is a child of the previous element. So if the 1D array is like this:

```
Array
(
    ['bar'] => 1 // I don't care of the values as of the moment
    ['foo'] => 1
    ['baz'] => 1
)
```

Element `foo` should be the child of `bar`, and element `baz` should be the child of `foo` for the tree array.

> Ok so the actual values of everything except the last element are
>   irrelevant?

Actually all values of the 1D array is irrelevant as of this moment. I am only concerned on constructing the tree array.

Comment: OK well you obviously need some kind of recursive function, but can you explain how you know that `key2` should be a child of `key1`, `key3` should be a child of `key2` etc based on the data you show?

Comment: Hi @DaveRandom. Please see edits.

Comment: Ok so the actual values of everything except the last element are irrelevant?

Comment: Actually all values of the 1D array is irrelevant as of this moment. I am only concerned on constructing the tree array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to use references.

```
function create_tree($arr) {
  $result = array();
  $ref = &$result;
  foreach ($arr as $key => $el) {
    $ref = array($key => $el);
    $ref =& $ref[$key];
  }
  return $result;
}
```

How it works:

```
$result = array(); // an array to hold the result

$ref = &$result; // start with a reference to the top level

foreach ($arr as $key => $el) { // iterate over the input array

  $ref = array($key => $el); // create this level in the array

  $ref =& $ref[$key]; // change the reference to be the new deepest level

}

return $result; // return the result
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/7HGCPv8B)

Comment: This works pretty well. Thanks. I never thought about references.

Answer (score 2):

[Assignment by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) appears to be useful for this.

```
$tree = array();
$node =& $tree;
foreach ($arr as $key => $a) {
    $node =& $node[$key];
    $node = array();
}
$node = end($arr);
```

Comment: Yes, or that does the job as well.